# Tikzposter theme creates a blank space

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, posters, tikzposter

I'm making a poster using `tikzposter` with the `basic` theme. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait, margin=0mm, innermargin=15mm,
blockverticalspace=15mm, colspace=15mm, subcolspace=8mm]{tikzposter}

\title{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering  The big poster fail}}
\author{Amir Sagiv}
\usetheme{Basic} % See Section 5

\begin{document}
\maketitle 
\end{document}
```

**The problem:** This latex produces a vertical blank space at the top, see here [image: here]

How can I make it go away?

**What I've tried so far:**

1. I used `\setlength{\voffset}{-1.75in}`, but this only pushes the blank space to the bottom.
2. If you erase the `\usetheme{Basic}` then the blank space goes away, but then the poster looks awful. As was remarked in the comments, most other themes do not behave this way.

What do you recommmend? Where's the problem? Is there's an alternative to the `\usetheme{Basic}`?

Comment: There are several predefined themes: `Default`, `Rays`,  `Basic`, `Simple`, `Envelope`, `Wave`, `Board`, `Autumn` and `Desert`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Interesting! Most themes don't behave the same way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can adjust `titletotopverticalspace` like so

[image]

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait, margin=0mm, innermargin=15mm,
blockverticalspace=15mm, colspace=15mm, subcolspace=8mm]{tikzposter}

\title{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering  The big poster fail}}
\author{Amir Sagiv}
\usetheme{Basic} % See Section 5

\begin{document}
\maketitle[titletotopverticalspace=-5mm]
\end{document}
```